# How to use built-in variable in proc (Tcl)

Tags: tcl

TCL has some built-in command.

For example `$env(some_env_var)`, I'll take some environment variable.

I use `$env(some_env_var)` in `proc`

```
proc pc {} {
  return $env(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS)
}

puts [pc]
```

then I get error:

```
$ tclsh ./t.tcl
can't read "env(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS)": no such variable
    while executing
"return $env(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS)"
    (procedure "pc" line 2)
    invoked from within
"pc"
    invoked from within
"puts [pc]"
    (file "./t.tcl" line 5)
```

`$env` seems invalid in scope of `proc`,

How should I modify `$env` to make it valid in the scope of `proc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to bring the `env` array into scope in your `pc` proc:

```
proc pc {} {
  global env
  return $env(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS)
}
```

Alternatively, use the full namespace path to env:

```
proc pc {} {
  return $::env(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS)
}
```